# Padding matrix for spacial filtering

Tags: image-processing

for examples, I have a 2x2 matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

Then I pad it with 2, it becomes,

```
x x x x x x 
x x x x x x
x x 1 2 x x
x x 3 4 x x
x x x x x x
x x x x x x
```

Then I use border_replicate to fill value to x

```
x x 1 2 x x
x x 1 2 x x
1 1 1 2 2 2
3 3 3 4 4 4
x x 3 4 x x
x x 3 4 x x
```

The problem is for the x that located at the vertex of the new matrix, if I use border_replicate, what will their value? ....

Thank you very much

Comment: hmmh, when you voted down, please give a short explain in the comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, it looks like the corners (clockwise from top left) would be 1, 2, 4, and 3.